# how to change parametres of api url in node js?

Tags: node.js

I am trying a news api and I can get news of different categories by changing the parametres like:- `https://news_api_example.app/news?type=education&limit=5'`  to - `https://news_api_example.app/news?type=sports&limit=5'`

What I want to do is to get news of all different categories at the same time.
Is there any way I can  do this without writing tens and twenties of functions inside `async.parallel` in node.js or if  `async.parallel` is only possible in such scenario is there a way to ease things up.
I know the we should avoid using loops as node.js is single threaded etc.

I am using `node-fetch` module to `fetch` the data from api in the standard way so I am not including any code but if you want it I can put it

THANKS :)

Comment: Ask the owners of the API - maybe there's a way to un-apply filtering, like dropping the `?type` from the query.

Comment: Dunno if thats possible. I am using one of the github versions of in shorts api